# Kafka & Avro producer - Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Im running schema-registry-confluent example with my local and I got an error when I modified the schema of the message:

This is my schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "io.confluent.tutorial.pojo.avro",
  "name": "OrderDetail",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "number",
      "type": "long",
      "doc": "The order number."
    },
    {
      "name": "date",
      "type": "long",
      "logicalType": "date",
      "doc": "The date the order was submitted."
    },
    {
      "name": "client",
      "type": { 
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Client",
        "fields": [
          { "name": "code", "type": "string" }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I tried to send this message on the producer:

```
{"number": 2343434, "date": 1596490462, "client": {"code": "1234"}}
```

But I got this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "example-topic-avro-value"; error code: 409
```

Comment: What exactly did you modify in the schema? What did it look like before? What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: what is the previous version of schema for subject "example-topic-avro-value"  ?

Comment: I didn’t understand why it is not a valid message for that schema. I only added the “client”, if I remove it all works fine.

Comment: I also met with similar issue when adding a new field to an existing schema, after adding a default value to a newly added field, it works. I guess the reason is that older records can't be deserialized if the new schema does not have a default value for a new filed.